# Hadoop-PCap-Lib Field Types

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, reflection, pcap

I'm trying to make a protobuf class that can more efficiently stream DNSPackets that have been captured using TCPDump.

I would like to know the types of all of the possible fields offered in this library:

```
DNSPacket Fields:
    QUERYID
    QR
    OPCODE
    RCODE
    QUESTION
    QNAME
    QTYPE
    ANSWER
    AUTHORITY
    ADDITIONAL
Packet Fields:
    TIMESTAMP
    TIMESTAMP_USEC
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS
    TTL
    IP_VERSION
    IP_HEADER_LENGTH
    IP_FLAGS_DF
    IP_FLAGS_MF
    IPV6_FLAGS_M
    FRAGMENT_OFFSET
    FRAGMENT
    LAST_FRAGMENT
    PROTOCOL
    SRC
    DST
    ID
    SRC_PORT
    DST_PORT
    TCP_HEADER_LENGTH
    TCP_SEQ
    TCP_ACK
    LEN
    UDPSUM
    UDP_LENGTH
    TCP_FLAG_NS
    TCP_FLAG_CWR
    TCP_FLAG_ECE
    TCP_FLAG_URG
    TCP_FLAG_ACK
    TCP_FLAG_PSH
    TCP_FLAG_RST
    TCP_FLAG_SYN
    TCP_FLAG_FIN
    /*Not sure bout these two*/
    REASSEMBLED_TCP_FRAGMENTS 
    REASSEMBLED_DATAGRAM_FRAGMENTS
```

My application is in Scala and I tried simple reflection on a few of the packets I captured, but many fields are null, which isn't helpful.

The library can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/hadoop-pcap/tree/master/hadoop-pcap-lib/src/main/java/net/ripe/hadoop/pcap)

Is there a simple way I can get the types of **ALL** of these fields? (Either programmatically or via a text source)

Thanks,
RDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached this in the most immediately obvious way.

I decided to use a sheer number of packets to tackle the problem, captured about 100,000 DNS Packets using Wireshark, and then saved the capture as a `.pcap` file.

I then ran the following on the file:

```
try {
  var dataInStream: DataInputStream = null
  //Open the file and set up the DataInputStream
  val f = new File(pCapFileName)
  if (f.getAbsoluteFile.exists) {
    val fis = new FileInputStream(f)
    dataInStream = new DataInputStream(fis)
    val dnsPcapReader = new DnsPcapReader(dataInStream)
    val pktIter = dnsPcapReader.iterator
    var counter = 0
    while (pktIter.hasNext) {
      counter += 1
      if (counter % 100 == 0) println(counter)
      val pCapFile = pktIter.next.asInstanceOf[DnsPacket]
      for (i <- 0 until types.length) {
        val tuple = types(i)
        val fieldName = tuple._1
        var className = Option(pCapFile.get(fieldName)).map(_.getClass).toString
        var numOccurances = tuple._3
        if(className.equals("None"))
          className = tuple._2.asInstanceOf[String]
        else
          numOccurances += 1
        val newTuple = (fieldName, className, numOccurances)
        types = types.updated(i, newTuple)
      }
    }
  }
  for {
    tuple <- types
  } printf("%s%-25s%-25s%-25s\n%s\n", "\t", tuple._1 + ":", tuple._2,
    "[" + tuple._3 + "]", spacer)
  //Close the stream
  dataInStream.close
} catch {
  case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Essentially, for every field name it checked for a value, which also then checked for the class of that value. Each time the corresponding space in the list was updated to reflect the field (not too elegant but it gets results in a reasonable fashion). Additionally it was handy to see what fields were common and which were not.

The results are below:

```
dst:                     Some(class java.lang.String)[98823]
```

---

```
dst_port:                Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98614]
```

---

```
fragment:                Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[98823]
```

---

```
fragment_offset:         Some(class java.lang.Long)[98799]
```

---

```
id:                      Some(class java.lang.Long)[98799]
```

---

```
ip_flags_df:             Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[98799]
```

---

```
ip_flags_mf:             Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[98799]
```

---

```
ip_header_length:        Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98823]
```

---

```
ip_version:              Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98823]
```

---

```
ipv6_flags_m:            null                     [0]
```

---

```
last_fragment:           null                     [0]
```

---

```
len:                     Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98823]
```

---

```
protocol:                Some(class java.lang.String)[98618]
```

---

```
reassembled_datagram_fragments:null                     [0]
```

---

```
reassembled_tcp_fragments:Some(class java.lang.Integer)[835]
```

---

```
src:                     Some(class java.lang.String)[98823]
```

---

```
src_port:                Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98614]
```

---

```
tcp_ack:                 Some(class java.lang.Long)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_ack:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_cwr:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_ece:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_fin:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_ns:             Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_psh:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_rst:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_syn:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_flag_urg:            Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_header_length:       Some(class java.lang.Integer)[96106]
```

---

```
tcp_seq:                 Some(class java.lang.Long)[96106]
```

---

```
ts:                      Some(class java.lang.Long)[100258]
```

---

```
ts_micros:               Some(class java.lang.Long)[100258]
```

---

```
ts_usec:                 Some(class java.lang.Double)[100258]
```

---

```
ttl:                     Some(class java.lang.Integer)[98823]
```

---

```
udp_length:              Some(class java.lang.Integer)[2508]
```

---

```
udpsum:                  Some(class java.lang.Integer)[2508]
```

---

```
dns_additional:          Some(class java.util.ArrayList)[320]
```

---

```
dns_answer:              Some(class java.util.ArrayList)[320]
```

---

```
dns_authority:           Some(class java.util.ArrayList)[320]
```

---

```
dns_flags:               Some(class java.lang.String)[320]
```

---

```
dns_opcode:              Some(class java.lang.String)[320]
```

---

```
dns_qname:               Some(class java.lang.String)[320]
```

---

```
dns_qr:                  Some(class java.lang.Boolean)[320]
```

---

```
dns_qtype:               Some(class java.lang.Integer)[320]
```

---

```
dns_queryid:             Some(class java.lang.Integer)[320]
```

---

```
dns_question:            Some(class java.lang.String)[320]
```

---

```
dns_rcode:               Some(class java.lang.String)[320]
```

---

There were three fields still with 0 occurrences, so their class types are still unknown:
   `ipv6_flags_m`, `last_fragment`, and `reassembled_datagram_fragments`

Seeing as `ipv6_flags_m` is a flag it is likely a boolean, I made the assumption that it was which leaves two fields. With no occurrences in 100,000 packets, I deemed these fields insignificant and omitted them from my list entirely.